# C# records constructor parameter default value empty IEnumerable

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, default, record, enumerable

I am converting this class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Strings { get; }

    public MyClass(IEnumerable<string>? strings = null)
    {
        Strings = strings ?? new List<string>();
    }
}
```

To a record. Currently I have this:

```
public record MyRecord(IEnumerable<string>? strings = null);
```

However, I can't find a way to default initialize the `IEnumerable` to an empty enumerable, as it must be a compile time constant. I tried static initializing a readonly array, but same problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since `IEnumerable<string>` is a reference type, the only possible default parameter is  `null`. There's absolutely nothing else you can stick there. But! You *can* reference the property from the *primary constructor* in the initialization of an explicitly declared "long-form" auto-property. This would allow you to coalesce the value as it's assigned to the property.

```cs
public record MyRecord(IEnumerable<string>? Strings = null)
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Strings { get; init; } = Strings ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

[See SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BiAdgVwBtCJhC4ACOXU8gWACgABAJgEZGmAGCptgFgDcnHnwB0AGQCWuAI7CGnAMwUEcAMYB7BCgoBZAJ4AlDdpQAKPkoA8fLgD4A/BQDKMBDIDmUCgF4KBMQAlIwA3owUkbwqVrZsDq7uXj6hFJ5wMIIUMlKZFAC+fokeuN4Ujs4AogRgiLRwYpVgAA4wBnEO5kEKURSMhYxAA)

This actually generates a constructor for your record similar to the one you had originally. Here's what the above link generates (with the nullable *attributes* converted back to `?`) for the constructor:

```cs
public MyRecord(IEnumerable<string>? Strings = null)
{
    <Strings>k__BackingField = Strings ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    base..ctor();
}
```

It's a little more verbose/not as compact as the one-liner but it's the only way to accomplish what you ask for with a `record` and it's still shorter than the non-`record` version.

Also note that if you look at the generated code, the property ends up being declared non-nullable, while the constructor parameter is nullable. Compare this to the single line version you started with, where the generated parameter would be nullable to match the primary constructor declaration. In this solution, you *could* change this behavior (if you needed to) and explicitly mark the long-form property nullable as well.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work well with nullable value parameters - C# insists that the parameter can't be bool? when the field is bool.